# Can't pull from the repository svn

Tags: xcode, svn, repository, pull

I want to pull changes from a visual svn repository using Xcode, but a window opens "Choose the working copies to pull.", but besides the working copy it is written uncommited changes. I commited the changes before wanting to pull the changes from the repository and I really can't understand why it isn't working.

Comment: issue `update` command. At least you have to in sync with your SVN server.

Comment: You mean that I should use that update command in the organizer-repositories?

Comment: Yes. Apparently your source is out of sync with your SVN server

Comment: I tried this and the same window appears "uncommited changes"